# How to install and use browserify with laravel?

Tags: laravel, npm, reactjs, browserify

I am doing my project in laravel and for dynamic views I am using react.js. But to divide react scripts into different modules I need to install browserify. But I don't have any idea of using npm. So, can anyone help me to install browserify in laravel and how to use it with my react script?

My 2nd question is I also want to install react tools to transform jsx to js, so, if anyone have an idea of installing it, then please help me..

Thank you :)

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: npm install -g browserify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whichever monolithic framework your using, there is usually a step in your application's lifecycle where you use tools from your stack to perform asset compilation and this becomes a part of your application's asset pipeline.

If you want to start with something quick and parallel to your existing Laravel sources, then you just need install Node.js in your environment, smack in a [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file and decide whether you want something like a complete build system like [`gulp`](http://gulpjs.com/), your [own build script](https://gist.github.com/substack/8313379) or just simply use [bash commands](https://gist.github.com/substack/7819530#file-package-json-L12) defined as reusable [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

You can then begin using Node.js and manage anything from building LESS sources, running a live-reload proxy like [Browsersync](http://www.browsersync.io/), building your client sources with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), etc. The simplest way to integrate this with your Laravel application is that you produce static assets like `index.css`, `index.js`, `icons.svg`, `sprites.png` on paths which can be resolved by your static file server and referenced in your application templates.